# getClipData() returning null when a single image is selected when working fine when multiple images are selected

Tags: android

Basically, I need to select multiple images. My code is working fine when I select multiple images but it's not working when I select a single image.

I am using this code to select the images

```
public void getPhotoFromGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
}
```

My onActivityResult() is

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("onActivityResult: ", "STARTED");
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        try {
            Log.i("Error: ", String.valueOf(data));
            ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
            Log.i("Error: ", String.valueOf(mClipData));
            .....

            .....
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I select multiple images, My code is working fine. But when I select a single image, data.getClipData() is returning null.
I basically need a list of URI of all the select images. I don't understand the problem.
Also, String.valueof(data) shows there is URI present when one image is selected but data.getClipData() still returning null.

Comment: android studio is just the IDE helping you to write your code, but it doesn't really have anything else to do with your question, so i've removed the tags. if you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically, you should add the tag, otherwise there's no reason to use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also, String.valueof(data) shows there is URI present when one image is selected but data.getClipData() still returning null

You will get that `Uri` from calling `data.getData()`, where `data` is the `Uri` delivered to `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: The URI in my case and using Java is returned by "result.getData().getData()", for example: @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        ...
        Bitmap bitmapFromUri = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(result.getData().getData()));
        ...

Comment: @nibbana: With `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`, `Uri` values can come via `ClipData`.